# Stimulsoft, assembly 'Stimulsoft.Data' is not found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

I have Upgraded stimulsoft report version from 2014.3.0.0 to 2021.1.1 (Installed Stimulsoft.Reports.Web 2021.1.1 from Nuget package manager) and added code to generate pdf report.
It is working perfectly when it is on local instance but it is throwing assembly error when deploy to live.

**Error is as follows :**

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Stimulsoft.Data, Version=2021.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ebe6666cba19647a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Stimulsoft.Data, Version=2021.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ebe6666cba19647a'
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiNameValidator.CorrectName(String str, Boolean checkKeywords, StiReport report, Boolean isDataExpression)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.GetReportName()
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.ScriptNew()
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Clear(Boolean generateNewScript)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.LoadPackedReport(Stream stream)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.LoadPackedReport(Byte[] bytes)
```

Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: Maybe you need a package-restore for publish?

Comment: @Rutuja: You should deploy listed components when deploying your application on a target: [https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/programming-manual/index.html?deployment.htm](https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/programming-manual/index.html?deployment.htm)

Comment: You often see this error because the reports are designed with an older version. Design and test a sample report with the new version of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was issue of deployment. MsBuild was not including indirect references while building application. so, I just updated Manifest file and it resolved issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing updated assembly redirects. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

This is what I would do in web.config :

```xml
<configuration>
<runtime>
 <assemblyBinding ...>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Stimulsoft.Data"
    publicKeyToken="ebe6666cba19647a" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2014.3.0.0" newVersion="2021.1.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
 </assemblyBinding >
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a build and deployment issue and the solution depends on the way you build and deploy the application. This is what I would do:

1. Check to see if the old dll **2014.3.0.0** is the one that is on the bin folder in the production server. If that is the case then you might have not updated all the references in the project.
2. Neither the old or the new dll are in the bin folder. This could happen because of a missing nuget restore step on the build server.
3. The new dll **2021.1.1** is on the bin folder. This means that **one of its dependencies** is missing from the bin folder. To find out which dependency is missing you need to decompile **Stimulsoft.Reports.Web 2021.1.1** dll and check that all the reference listed in that dll are located in the bin folder. If not then you need to add the reference to the missing dll manually to your project.

NOTE: I use [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) for decompiling.